# Track "copy to my calendar" of shared google calendar events using Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I own a calendar which is shared with a certain number of people (subscribers). I would like to keep track of which events the subscribers add/copy to their personal calendars. The calendar is created by a spreadsheet using Apps Scripts and I have full access on anything needed. The emails of the subscribers are known but I can't access info on their side.

I would be happy with a boolean of a kind showing if an event has been copied, but if that's possible then I believe I'll be able to also count which and how many subscribers copied which events.

Comment: What is your question? Please see "How to ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, the Calendar API doesn't have any way to obtain if and event was copied. In any case, the event copy option is just a template from the original event that can be completely modified before being created.

Comment: @probitaille sorry, thought my question was clear enough.

Comment: @AndresDuarte Thank you for confirming. I'm not sure I can modify the copy option to function as I want, but I might have a look.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Calendar API doesn't have any way to obtain if and event was copied. In any case, the event copy option is just a template from the original event that can be completely modified before being created.